# Projective representations of a finite abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, abelian-groups

Projective representations of a group $G$ are classified by the second group cohomology $H^2(G,U(1))$. If $G$ is finite and abelian, it is isomorphic to the direct product of cyclic groups

$$
G\cong C_{n_1,...,n_k}:=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times ...\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}
$$

Hence I was wandering if there is any known result for

$$
H^2(C_{n_1,...,n_k},U(1))
$$

I know that
$$
H^2(\mathbb{Z}_n,U(1))=0 \ , \ \ \ \ \ \ H^2(\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2},U(1))\cong \mathbb{Z}_{\text{gcd}(n_1,n_2)}
$$
but I don't know about are a general result or even a result for $k=3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is $\ \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i<j}\ \mathbb{Z}/\!\gcd(n_i,n_j)$. The reason is that for $G$ finite, $H^2(G,U(1))$ is the dual abelian group of $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})$. Now use the Künneth formula.

Comment: Thanks, does it follows from the Kunneth formula for Eilenberg-MacLane spaces?

Comment: Also, this was a preliminary question, without editing with major changing I posted a follow up question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452171/trivial-group-cohomology-induces-trivial-cohomology-of-subgroups

Comment: I edited the answer to give the reason why.